# Does Bluetooth 5.x / LE Audio also improve calls? (HSP/HFP profiles)

Tags: bluetooth

[This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/) describes my main annoyance with Bluetooth: They are perfectly fine for listening to music with AptX (and the new LC3).

But till now, it was impossible to replace a "traditional" headset (whether wired or with a proprietary USB dongle) with a bluetooth headset because as soon as you activate the mic, it switches to the HSP/HFP profiles, which use low bitrate, bad codec mono audio, and quality drops to terrible.

That means I can't drop into discord and watch a movie. (Well I can, but audio will suck)

Has there been any progress on this with Bluetooth 5.x / Bluetooth LE Audio? Have the HSP/HFP profiles been updated to also use LC3, or are there new bi-directional profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LE audio website](https://www.bluetooth.com/learn-about-bluetooth/recent-enhancements/le-audio/) hilariously only focuses on hearing aids. The information content regarding microphone quality is damn near 0 (and the spec isn't out yet), but in one side remark of a talk there was a slight hint that microphone quality could be better.

This impression is aided by the new architecture allowing *high quality audio* and *some* microphone transmission simultaneously. The use case presented was talking to a voice assistant while listening to music, but one can hope it'll also apply to acceptable quality voice calls.

However, as for some reason regarding the topic, none of the so far available press releases by Qualcomm or Nordic Semiconductor are mentioning this as a feature.

Comment: It's [out now](https://www.bluetooth.com/learn-about-bluetooth/recent-enhancements/le-audio/le-audio-specifications) and you have everything and the kitchen sink. A cursory look at the TMAP (*Telephony and Media Audio Profile*, which is supposed to "replicate and extend the two primary use cases for Bluetooth Classic Audio") refers to a BAP (*Basic Audio Profile*) table for mandatory codecs to support in the "Call Terminal" role. The highest guaranteed quality is 32_2 (aka LC3 at 32kHz and 64 kbps), which is not great.. but still it blows CVSD away. And I guess vendors can always support more.

Comment: Lol, nevermind. It wasn't until ***yesterday*** (12 July 2022) that the spec was actually 100% [finalized](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/07/whats-bluetooth-le-audio-explaining-the-latest-wireless-tech-standard/).

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be an [extension called FastStream](https://www.reddit.com/r/bluetooth/comments/gp7c2q/aptxll_and_faststream/), which supports a voice backchannel in A2DP.

In that reddit post is a non authorative, non-exhaustive [list of supported features per device](https://btcodecs.valdikss.org.ru/codec-compatibility/). None of my BT headphones support FastStream, so I can not test that.

Comment: FastStream is fascinating. Not from a technology point of view, but everything around it: Qualcomm has poured resources into making it, it's a real differentiating feature, but neither QC nor the Headset manufacturers are advertising it. It's basically being kept a secret. There are also no implementations outside of (extremely rare) dongles and [a patch to PulseAudio](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2019-June/031168.html) by Pali Rohár.

Comment: It was actually [CSR](https://web.archive.org/web/20150307015353/http://www.csr.com/news/pr/release/54/en) that created it, and there's also *[AuriStream](https://web.archive.org/web/20080930075517/http://www.csr.com/products/bc6rom_over.htm)* [actually](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-bluetooth/20191211144041.nu5tngwp25i6fjup@pali/T/). But I believe the more modern workaround into this bloodline is [AptX-LL](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/972#note_1027368).